# No access to internet

Tags: 12.04, sound, video, internet

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday but cannot play song or videos. I don't have access to internet. So what can be the possible solution?

Comment: Why do you have "software files in .tar format"? You usually don't need to download software in that format. You can install software with the [Ubuntu-Software-Center](http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/features/ubuntu-software-centre). Do you want to install a special software, that you don't find in the software-center? How do you connect to the internet, LAN or WLAN? Maybe you have to activate the [wireless-driver](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7EfDIGvW8s&t=1m14s). For some audio- and videoformats, you have to install the [proprietary codecs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7EfDIGvW8s).

Answer (score 1):

you can connect to internet by cable connection . and you can open adddional drivers. you will see you wifi driver . install it.

and ubuntu newer come codec to play anything you must install in ubuntu software center .